# XSLT for replace attribute in XML element if it exists in another XML?

Tags: xslt, merge, replace

I have 2 files

catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <CD Title="Still got the blues" vinyl="unknown"/>
    <CD Title="When a man loves a woman" vinyl="unknown"/>
</catalog>
```

vinyl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Vinyl>
    <Album>
        <Title>When a man loves a woman</Title>
        <Vinyl>Yes</Vinyl>
    </Album>
</Vinyl>
```

How to produce such output.xml with xslt?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <CD Title="Still got the blues" vinyl="unknown"/>
    <CD Title="When a man loves a woman" vinyl="yes"/>***   
</catalog>
```

***mark this line becouse it changed in output.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following transform, uses **catalog.xml** as input and loads **vinyl.xml** using `document()`. It performs the merge just by making a simple test.

---

[XSLT 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vinyl" select="document('test_i2.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@vinyl">
        <xsl:attribute name="vinyl">
            <xsl:variable name="test" select="
                 $vinyl/Vinyl/Album[Title=current()/../@Title]/Vinyl"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$test">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This template for the attribute is less immediate, but it exploits pure XPath:

```
<xsl:template match="@vinyl">
    <xsl:attribute name="vinyl">
        <xsl:value-of select="
          $vinyl/Vinyl/Album[Title=current()/../@Title]/Vinyl
          |
          self::node()[count($vinyl/Vinyl/Album[Title=current()/../@Title])=0]"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Now simplified by matching the attribute directly.

Comment: @Kirill thanks. That's the most immediate answer to me. Would like to see an alternative not using control instructions like choose.

Comment: @empo really thanks I was making with nested loop on vinyl.xml and catalog.xml. And get upset, becouse no success

Comment: @popalka you are welcome. Thanks for the feedback. See edited answer for full XPath usage.