# Passing xml as parameter to xslt and replacing the xml

Tags: xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XSLT for replace attribute in XML element if it exists in another XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996998/xslt-for-replace-attribute-in-xml-element-if-it-exists-in-another-xml)

I have two XML:

First XML:

```
<FirstXML>
  <catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
  </catalog>
</FirstXML>
```

Second XML:

```
<SecondXML>
  <catalog>
         <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
  </catalog>
</SecondXML>
```

I want to Transform my First XML using XSLT. The cd node of first xml should be replaced with cd node of second xml.

Resulting XML from XSLT transformation:

```
<FirstXML>
  <catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
  </catalog>
</FirstXML>
```

Please help me with XSLT for this. I think we would need to pass the Second XML as a parameter to the XSLT, I am trying to do that. I am very new to XSLT so might not be coding it correctly.
Any inputs on how we can do this would be helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996998/xslt-for-replace-attribute-in-xml-element-if-it-exists-in-another-xml/6997207#6997207

Comment: Using `document()`, as suggested in the answers, you can pass in the filename or URI to the second document as a parameter and then use that parameter value to load the document e.g. `document($secondXML)`

Answer (score 5):

> I think we would need to pass the Second XML as a parameter to the
>   XSLT.

**This is possible, but not necessary at all**.

A more convenient way is to pass to the transformation just the filepath to the document and use the XSLT **[`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document)** function for parsing and accessing it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDocLink" select=
  "'file:///c:/temp/delete/SecondXml.xml'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="document($pDocLink)/*/*[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided "first" document**:

```
<FirstXML>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
</FirstXML>
```

**and the "second" document is placed at: `c:\temp\delete\SecondXml.xml`** :

```
<SecondXML>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS Records</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
</SecondXML>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<FirstXML>
   <catalog>
      <cd>
         <title>Hide your heart</title>
         <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
         <country>UK</country>
         <company>CBS Records</company>
         <price>9.90</price>
         <year>1988</year>
      </cd>
   </catalog>
</FirstXML>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#document) function, use it to work with several input sources.
The description of your problem is too vague to make more detailed recommendations. Try to search some tutorials, e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcombxslt/

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at the [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#document) function. Passing an XML tree in as a parameter works is some XML systems, not others.

If you have a variable such as

```
<xsl:variable name="source" select="document('filename.xml')//catalog"/>
```

then accessing the variable `$source` would give you the root of your CD branch

**EDIT**

Just for clarity of my answer to Dimitre Novatchev, and as I said you could do it, although in 90% of times you would want to use the document function, it is possible to pass a node fragment in through to a stylesheet from a C# application with AddParam, and could be used when you are generating that data from your own application, and don't need to write it (or where it isn't practical).

So for a stylesheet such as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:param name="bonnie_tyler"/>

        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="cd[ancestor::FirstXML]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($bonnie_tyler)//cd/*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

the First and Second XML as per your original question, you could use the pass the nodes in such as:

```
        try
        {
            XslCompiledTransform xt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            Assembly ass = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            Stream strm = ass.GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApplication1.testparam.xslt");
            XmlTextReader xmr = new XmlTextReader(strm);
            xt.Load(xmr);
            xmr.Close();

            XmlDocument originalDocument = new XmlDocument();
            strm = ass.GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApplication1.FirstXML.xml");
            originalDocument.Load(strm);
            XmlDocument replacementNode = new XmlDocument();
            strm = ass.GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApplication1.SecondXML.xml");
            replacementNode.Load(strm);

            XsltArgumentList arg = new XsltArgumentList();
            arg.AddParam("bonnie_tyler", "", replacementNode);

            StringBuilder htmlOutput = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(htmlOutput);

            xt.Transform(originalDocument, arg, writer);

            Console.Out.Write(htmlOutput.ToString());
        }
```

which would give you your desired output (although obviously you wouldn't be loading the files from disk as here)

Comment: Can I input the xml in C# using xslt.AddParam() method and use that parameter in the XSLT?

Comment: If you are doing that you can put it in xslt.AddParam(), but then to use it you will have to prefix it with msxsl:node-set($paramname) as otherwise it will appear as a string. Which means you need to add the msxsl namespace.

Comment: @Woody: Your last comment contains a false statement about the `msxsl:node-set()` extension function. Applying it on a string results in error.

Comment: No, I was just sloppy with my language. Agreed applying it to a string results in an error but you can pass an XMLDocument or XPathNodeNavigator as a parameter which you can use with msxsl:node-set(). Agreed it is better doing it with document() which is why my answer said that, but I once had to do it with no files on the system, which offered few options apart from that